# What is asymptotic complexity of List.Add?

Tags: c#, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I've found that there is a lot of controversy about asymptotic complexity of `List.Add()`. The source of it I suspect is the worst case scenario [that causes underlying array to resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx#datastructures20_1_topic5) and would logically be `O(n)` operation. However, the [array grows twice in size](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,407) each time list runs out of space. That makes amount of resizes needed for `n` elements be proportional to `log(n)`.

Does not that mean that asymptotic complexity of `Add` operation in average case will be `O(n/log(n))`?

The real benchmark for `List.Add()` is below. However, benchmarks are not really expressive for such operation - we might be running out of memory prior to any deviation from straight (in logarithmic scale) line becomes visible.

[image: benchmark]

Comment: When the array growths indeed the existing N/2 elements are moved. That's why you think it's log N. But the new yet unusued capacity growth exponentially. That counters the effect. The first element is moved log N times. The last N/2 elements are moved 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that the [*amortized complexity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) of `List.Add()` can be calculated by summing the resize operations and then multiplying by number of total additions made to the list.

```
T(n) = (2 + 4 + 8 + ... + n/2 + n) / n
```

But note that the summation is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), and we can do better than assuming it's (summation) `n*log(n)`:

```
T(n) < 2n/n = 2 -> T(n) is in O(1)
```

---

Note: Here I am assuming you mean `add()` as appending. Inserting an element in an arbitrary location takes `O(n)` time, and you will have to account for that as well, which will change the end result from `O(1)` amortized complexity to `O(n)` amortized complexity.

Comment: Great job explaining the amortized complexity as well

Comment: So that in order to add n elements list will move 2n elements, right?